# Apex PageMessages are not showing up when using ActionStatus

Tags: visualforce

I am unable to show `<apexPage:Messages>` when using along with `<apex:ActionStatus>`.Below is the code-piece I'm using. Action status is required to handle duplicate submission of records and if I remove action status, page messages work perfectly.
Please suggest.

```
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pgblck">
            <apex:actionStatus id="mySaveStatus">
                <apex:facet name="stop">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" status="mySaveStatus" rerender="pgblck" />
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:image value="/img/loading32.gif" style="height: 15px;" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Processing..." status="mySaveStatus" disabled="true" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" 
                                status="mySaveStatus" rerender="pgblck"/>
```

instead of this rerender the form

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit" 
                                status="mySaveStatus" rerender="theForm"/>
```

You are not `rerending` the `pagemessage`. thats why you are not able to see the message.

Answer (score 2):

What Tushar says is correct, you have to `rerender` the `<apex:pageMessages` as well.

In addition to Tushar's solution, you can do the following way also.

Give a `id` to the `<apex:pageMessages` tag and add this to the `rerender` attribute (pgblck and errmsg) of the command button.

```
    <apex:pagemessages id="errmsg"/>
        .....
        .....
    <apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit"
            status="mySaveStatus" rerender="pgblck,errmsg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tushar and saroj's answer, as a bit low detail answer,
Once you put the status attribute for the command button , you have turned it to a ajax call, that means you have to rerender your page partially.

Thats why you have to put reRender attribute on commandbutton.